# component function re-rendering onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a react application. This specific Component has many different forms. As such, I have created external functions and am calling these component functions when I want to display a particular form.

Example:

```
const Create = () => {
    const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(true);

    const [noBoats, setNoBoats] = useState();
    const [noHouses, setNoHouses] = useState();

    const [isForm1, setIsForm1] = useState(true);

    const validateForm = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        if (input['name'] == 'no_boats') {
            setNoBoats(input.value)

            if (input.value != '') {
                if (between(input.value, 0, 4)) {
                    setFormValid(true)
                } else {
                    setFormValid(false)
                }
            }
        }

        if (input['name'] == 'no_houses') {
            setNoHouses(input.value)

            if (input.value != '') {
                if (between(input.value, 0, 8)) {
                    setFormValid(true)
                } else {
                    setFormValid(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const Form1 = () => {
      return (
      <>

        <form className={styles.form} id="form1" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <div className={styles.form_group}>
            <label htmlFor="no_houses">Number of Houses</label>
            <input type="text" name="no_houses" autoFocus="autoFocus" onChange={validateForm} value={noHouses}/>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.form_group}>
            <label htmlFor="no_boats">Number of Boats</label>
            <input type="text" name="no_boats" autoFocus="autoFocus" onChange={validateForm} value={noBoats}/>
          </div>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </>
      );
    }

    return (
            <div className={styles.all_forms}>
                  {isForm1 && <Form1 />}
            </div>

    );
}
```

When I go to fill out "Number of Boats" and "Number of Houses", the input loses focus after the first character. I have tried adding `autoFocus="autoFocus"` to both inputs, but that does not work either. Can any please explain what is going on?

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I am loading in the `Form1` component using `<Form />` and when the state updates it re-renders that form. I unfortunately have about 10 different forms so I can't really put them all in the main `render()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time the `Create` component rerenders the `Form1` component is redeclared, which (*obviously*) is a new component reference and will remount the component. This is the reason input focus is lost.

Declare `Form1` outside any other React component on its own so it's a stable reference. You'll need to pass all the callbacks and values in as props.

```
const Form1 = ({
  formValid,
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  noBoats,
  noHouses
}) => {
  return (
    <form
      className={styles.form}
      id="form1"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <div className={styles.form_group}>
        <label htmlFor="no_houses">Number of Houses</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="no_houses"
          autoFocus="autoFocus"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={noHouses}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.form_group}>
        <label htmlFor="no_boats">Number of Boats</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="no_boats"
          autoFocus="autoFocus"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={noBoats}
        />
      </div>

      <button disabled={!formValid} type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

```
const Create = () => {
  const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(true);

  const [noBoats, setNoBoats] = useState("");
  const [noHouses, setNoHouses] = useState("");

  const [isForm1, setIsForm1] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isValid = true;

    if (noBoats && !between(noBoats, 0, 4)) {
      isValid = false;
    }

    if (noHouses && !between(noHouses, 0, 8)) {
      isValid = false;
    }
    setFormValid(isValid);
  }, [noBoats, noHouses, setFormValid]);

  const handleChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { name, value } = currentTarget;

    if (input.name === 'no_boats') {
      setNoBoats(input.value);
    }

    if (input.name === 'no_houses') {
      setNoHouses(input.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.all_forms}>
      {isForm1 && (
        <Form1 
          formValid={formValid}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          noBoats={noBoats}
          noHouses={noHouses}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is a nice fix! Thank you! However, it seems as though the form will submit if only 1 of the input fields passes the validation... Do you know how to fix this? Especially if I am dealing with more than 2 variables. @DrewReese

Comment: @sfhasfasf Ah, I yeah, I see why. A good general pattern is to process all the form fields and only set the invalid state when a field is invalid. Right now each field is checked ***and*** setting the validation state independently. I'll edit with a suggestion.

Comment: @sfhasfasf I split the logic of updating the field state from the field validation. The main issue was that only one field is updated at-a-time, but there's only the one form-level validation state, so if you leave one field invalid and edit another to be valid, the form is valid. Now the validation is an effect from updating any field, and all field state is checked each time any one of them update.